# how to refactor a manually deployed single instance app into a client deployed multi-instance or multi-tenant app

Tags: javascript, web-applications, deployment, architecture, meteor

I have an meteor.js application that can be manually configured and deployed for a single instance quite nicely.

It is now time to refactor the application's architecture and build out the infrastructure around the app to allow it to be client deployed and update-able.

I'd like to have client come to a page where they can sign-up for the app, an instance or a tenancy would be automatically setup for them, and they could start using it. On the back-end there would be infrastructure to manage updates to the application.

There are some obvious decision that need to be made:

- Do I refactor it to be multi-tenant? (more application code modifications)
- Do I refactor it to be multi-instance? (more infrastructure build-out and code)
- Is it a hybrid? (one application but multiple databases)

What tests does one apply to determine the correct answer to the above question? and what are the pros and cons of each?

Once that decision has been made, does there exist design patterns to guide or inspire a proper refactor, and/or what learning resources exist out there for someone who has not built a multi-tenant or multi-instance app?

If its multi-instancing should the instancing and updating be part of the application itself or is there another layer of code and tools that should be built to manage that part?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I count 3 questions here, and you might find it valuable to split them into separate threads.  At any rate:

1) What test to determine the correct architecture? Well, a hard-assed look at how much it's going to cost to support each architecture vs. how quickly each can be implemented & how many waiting customers you have seems in order.  Hard-assed because, frankly, you probably already have a preference, and unless you're willing to set that aside the answer I give here is moot.  If this is for a business, remember that revenue rules -- without revenue even the most beautiful & elegant architecture is unimportant.  With revenue, you can fix most architecture mistakes in time.

2) What are good design patterns for multi-tenant, embed-able applications?  I'm not sure that design patterns are the right answer, but rather data management & testing rigor.  The goal here is to ensure that Client A's customers will never get a hint of Client B's customer data, even if a single individual is a user of both Client A and Client B.  Careful attention to API keys and session key management is the order of the day.

3) Instance management in app, or a separate tool?  I'm going to go out on a limb, and suggest that nobody will be able to satisfactorily answer this question without an analysis of your current application and infrastructure.  Maybe you have an application that is mostly self deploying, and only needs a few more lines to set up a new DB, or launch a new AWS instance, or whatever...  Or maybe you have a highly manual process.  This may also be influenced by your choice of architecture from Question 1, and/or how much time you have.  See note about revenue from Question 1.

Comment: I look at your answer and for me the take away is that I need to educate myself. For 1) I really don't have a preference and that's probably because I am a noob and don't understand the full or partial implications of choosing one route vs. the other... I don't know what will take longer because I don't have a vision for how to implement either. In that same vein I don't have forsight into the costs for supporting either architecture.

Comment: For 2) maybe pattern is the wrong concept, but my point is that there are tutorials and resources galore on how to make a single instance app, but I can find almost nothing on how to architect that app to be multi-tenant or how to build the infrastructure required to enable and manage a multi-instance variant... I suppose I could just take a stab at it, and stab it over and over again until it starts to work out but I feel like this is a problem that has been tackled many times, and it would be a bad idea to try to do it myself without at least having looked around at how others have solved it

Comment: If this is for a business, that has real potential customers now, you would benefit from getting a professional programmer involved, and take on the sales and product ownership.  If this is a learning exercise, then there's no point in worrying about what the perfect architecture is all about.

Comment: perfect is not the goal, informed and directed learning is the goal... maybe the answer is in fact that you can only learn about this stuff through trial and error and there is no way to glean best practices or good methodology from people who have already played in this domain space

Comment: Multi-tenant is HARD.  Many mature companies with large component of full time staff struggle with true multi-tenantism.  This is why there's no tutorial out there; it's actually pretty damned uncommon, faked with a layer of infrastructure smoke and mirror and bundled in professional services.  Best to just try to see what works. :)

Comment: Thanks! I appreciate the dialog. I will probably pursue a multi-instance approach, at least for my first go round.